# VMware horizon client 5.4 installation

Tags: vmware, linux-mint

I am using linux ubuntu mint and i want to install VWware horizon client 5.4. after download bundle file, I have an error during bundle file installation:

```
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Unable to load gtk: No module named gtk, falling back to console.
You must accept the VMware Horizon Client End User License Agreement
to continue.  Press Enter to proceed.
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it with the console, look here: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-Client-for-Linux/2006/horizon-client-linux-installation/GUID-F563F1E1-D9BD-4C42-80DC-4A3EB015FD65.html

input: sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle --console

always confirm with enter until point 12.11
There you have to confirm with yes. If you press enter again you have to confirm the whole text again. There are probably better solutions :D

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this problem as I did today, the bundle has to be run under sudo:

```
sudo ./VMware-Horizon-Client-2006-8.0.0-16522670.x64.bundle
```

Comment: Not in my case (Ubuntu 20.04). But `--console` option do it.